# best practices for determing a user or admin from rest api

Tags: angular, rest, api, jwt

I'm creating a REST API to serve a front-end, but I'm unclear on a few things, and hoping someone can shed some light on best practices to this approach.

The API is Flask, and I am using JWT. So, when a user properly authenticates (passes the correct username/md5 password) I am passing back a JWT. I also store the JWT in the database against the username to ensure that there is only one JWT per user at any give time. Even if he logs in from another PC, I have created a procedure to blacklist the current token.

What I am unclear on is how the front-end (lets say like Angular for example), can determine whether the user is an admin or a standard user.  Should I pass back (0 or 1 for example) so that the front-end would know to hide certain navigation links? If you store something into a cookie, a user could still change that value and access the admin links, so maybe that is where I am confused.

Also, on the front-end, how do you handle checking if the user has been revoked? Let's say he is logged in, token is revoked, and goes to click on another member-only link. Should we look at the rest response to determine if he is valid? For example, if the token expires we return "Token Revoked"

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, using a JWT *and* a database state somewhat defeats the purpose. JWTs are mostly meant so your backend can be stateless.

Comment: And yes, pass *some* flag from your login REST API back to your frontend to tell it what kind of user it is. And even if your user manipulates something client-side, they may be able to access the *admin templates* and such, but they should never be able to get admin *data* from the API. If you even want to hide the templates, then you need to fetch them from the server after login and do permission checking there.

Comment: @deceze If you don't store the token, then how do you track who has what token and invalidate the token?

Comment: I'm saying if you need that statefulness, then you may just use something like session ids instead of JWT. Not that it matters a lot though.

Comment: @deceze thans for those points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would retrieve the user profile ( all the information you don't save in the JWT ) at the page load. If you are building a *Single Page Application*, this will happen once. This data would contain information about the user and their permissions. Keep in might that anything that is returns in Javascript can be altered and should never be trusted by your backend. This is why it is important to validate your user permission front-end and backend.

As for your revoke token problem, Once again, it is the job of the backend to validate that. Your frontend can have a middleware that listen for invalid token response and do something accordingly. There is also an expiration date on your token, I don't like to use it, but it's there.

Comment: So it is okay to return a 0 or 1 to the frontend to let them know what kind of user is logging in? I have the API layer authenticate all requests anyway using the JWT, so even if the user was able to change some value (0 or 1) to see the admin pages, he still couldnt get access to the data.

For the expired token, could it be that the frontend checks the response, and if it says like "Token Expired" the user is logged out?

Comment: Exactly, The user is going to know what type of user they are by the data they see anyways. So at this point, as long as you validate every action on your backend, it is going to be ok. As for your expired token, that is exactly how i would do it. You have a middleware that check response, if one of them is something like `401, expired token`, you redirect them to the login page. @dataviews

Answer (score 2):

JWT has a solution for everything you said.

Inside a JWT token you can write anything you want, username, token expiration time, roles, etc. There are libraries in NPM that you can add to your project and use them to read the token claims.

Another way is that you can create an API that will serve extra information about the current request. For example after you get the token in Angular, you call the API with the token and server tells you your permissions, expire time, etc.

> Also, on the front-end, how do you handle checking if the user has
>   been revoked?

One option is to write a HTTP interceptor and monitor server's response status code. If server responds with a 401 it means that you are not authenticated and you either didn't attach any token or if you did, it is expired, There are also two unofficial HTTP status codes: 498 for Invalid Token and 499 for Token Required that you can use in you backend.

Another option is to monitor the token expiration time that you should get from server. Again, a HTTP interceptor will do the math and check if the current token is still valid.

Comment: I like these points, thank you very much. I've decided to save tokens against the user in the DB to ensure that only one valid token is given to any user at a time, and to invalidate this token when they login again or log out, or if the user is edited by an admin. The option to intercept is good, thank you very much